# 'System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntityContainerMapping' from assembly 'EntityFramework

Tags: .net

My VS 2012 installation stop working after using it for month.

I have an application where I used Database First, Entity Framework. When the database change i just use ADO Entity framework Wizard to update db classec (edmx file).

Then two days ago, i get this error. I can't find any solution. I try repair i vs 2012. I search on the net, but coulden't find anything.

Then i uninstall VS 2012 and install vs 2013 - same error. I also install/uninstall latest version of EFtools a couple of times - but still the same error. I am running Windows 7. I don't know what this is.

Any good idea out there?

Here is the complete error message:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception:
   'System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntityContainerMapping' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VersioningFacade.ReverseEngineerDb.DbDatabaseMappingBuilder.Build(SimpleMappingContext mappingContext)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelGenerator.GenerateModel(List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModels(String storeModelNamespace, ModelBuilderSettings settings, List`1 errors)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine.GenerateModel(ModelBuilderSettings settings, ModelBuilderEngineHostContext hostContext)'.
```

Comment: You do not say what Language you are using, but do you have an imports or a using `System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping` at the top of your class. Also do you have a reference to it in your references.

Comment: I am using C#. The problem happen always. With my exisiting application as well as when I create a new application. I create a new console application - us "add new item" ADO Entity framework. When the wizard start import work, i get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Entity framework tools 6.1.1 as it has a bug! 
Use entity framework tools 6.0.2